# what are some of the common routers people use for penetration testing?

Tags: penetration-test, wireless, router

So, I was looking for a router to penetration test on because the one I have is very difficult. What are some of the well-known routers that are supposed to work for beginners to penetration test on?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what kind of penetration testing you aim to do?

Comment: If your are looking for routers with well known bugs see http://routersecurity.org/bugs.php

Comment: As in pen testing *against* the router, like trying to access/change configuration things you shouldn't be able to access, finding unsecured traversal paths that aren't supposed to exist into a LAN, etc.?  If so, are these routers home/home office "routers" (which are really very basic routers, switches, firewalls, and often wireless access points rolled into one device), corporate-grade networking routers, corporate-grade firewalls...the way you're going to approach testing the security of all those examples can/will vary a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Pentesters do not use any "common" routers. As a pentester you should be able to perform a penetration test on any device. If a device is too difficult, it means you need to try harder.

Comment: it's a bit harsh, but we all go through the same process.